# SNC name of ABAP System

Tags: security, abap, sap-basis

I need to find out the SNC name of an ABAP System, which I can enter in server configuration in SAP Logon, so I can connect using single sign on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this information is contained in profile parameter `snc/identity/as`, which is accessible via `RZ10`

Comment: Mark this as answer

Answer (score 0):

you can navigate through transaction SM59 (RFC Destinations) and check the connection details for the ABAP system, which should include the SNC name if SNC is enabled.